# How does $age to age column works in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following code:

```
  test("test $") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().master("local").appName("$").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)).toDF("name", "age")
    df.select($"name").show()

    spark.stop()


  }
```

The `$` in `$"name"` is defined in the implicit class:

```
  implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
    def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
          new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
    }
  }
```

With this implicit class, The `$ method` is defined for the class StringContext
so that the following code is correct:

```
val x = StringContext("Hello")
x.$("World")
```

I would ask how the implicit conversion works in `df.select($"name").show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringContext` is class of Scala standard library: `This class provides the basic mechanism to do String Interpolation`, like

```
val name = "Jennie"
val statement = s"Her name is $name" // s actually is a method of StringContext that is used to insert its arguments between corresponding parts of the string context`
```

And implicit class `StringToColumn` is to enrich `$` method to `StringContext` class.

```
implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
    def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
          new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*)) // call s method
    }
  }
```

Assume `select` requires argument of `column` type. The call `select($"column_string")`, scala compiler won't give up immediately, it looks up for implicit conversion between `StringContext` to `column` and it finds out `StringToColumn`.

Update about why `s("Her name is $name")` is incorrect. Because when scala compiler see `s"Her name is $name"` it's going to rewrite as `StringContext("Her name is ", "").s(name)`. If you use `s("...")` the compiler considers `s` as a function not indicator of `String Interpolation`.

You can verify it by create a dummy scala file like `test.scala`

```
class A{
    val name = "Jennie"
    val a = s"Her name is $name"
}
```

then using `scalac -print test.scala`, it will show you the code after rewriting phase.

```
package <empty> {
  class A extends Object {
    private[this] val name: String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def name(): String = A.this.name;
    private[this] val a: String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def a(): String = A.this.a;
    def <init>(): A = {
      A.super.<init>();
      A.this.name = "Jennie";
      A.this.a = new StringContext(scala.Predef.wrapRefArray(Array[String]{"Her name is ", ""}.$asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]())).s(scala.Predef.genericWrapArray(Array[Object]{A.this.name()}));
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain why   `$"colname"` works but `$("colname")` not?

Comment: `s("Her name is $name")` is also incorrect, but `s"Her name is $name"` is correct, @cue, could you please explain?